# How to keep next js data in sync across re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next js app that fetches a users profile data on a server rendered 'page' component. Within that page, I pass the fetched data to a bunch of client side components that let users view and edit the data in their profile. When a user edits data, I send fetch requests to an api to update the database, and I use optimistic ui updates to update the ui. Now, if I re-render this component, it pulls in the initial data that was fetched when the page loaded, but it doesn't pull in the most current data unless I reload the entire page. How can I keep these client side components in sync with the most current data after re-renders?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: All i had to do was import {useRouter, usePathname} from 'next/navigation', instantiate the router, and then call router.replace(usePathname()) every time a  user updates data. 2ez.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).